# menú desplegable con bootstrap

Tags: html, bootstrap

como se realiza para que en la opcion agregar me despliegue otra lista que sea trabajadores y empresarios

el codigo que tengo es el siguiente

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>afiliar</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylemenu.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abril+Fatface" rel="stylesheet"> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>

 <div class="navegacion ">   
<nav class=" menu navegacion-principal navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light ">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" 
data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      


   <li class="nav-item dropdown active text-light">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-light" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" 
data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-id-card"></i> Afiliaciones</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="index2.php?pag=registrarAfiliado">Agregar</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="index2.php?pag=consultar">Consultar</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="index2.php?pag=actualizar">Actualizar</a>

         </div>
        </li>


     

    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
</div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes esta otra opción sin el uso de JavaScript...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>afiliar</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">
<style>
    .sidebar-nav {
        padding: 9px 0;
    }

    .dropdown-menu .sub-menu {
        left: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        visibility: hidden;
        margin-top: -1px;
    }

    .dropdown-menu li:hover .sub-menu {
        visibility: visible;
    }

    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
        display: block;
    }

    .nav-tabs .dropdown-menu, .nav-pills .dropdown-menu, .navbar .dropdown-menu {
        margin-top: 0;
    }

    .navbar .sub-menu:before {
        border-bottom: 7px solid transparent;
        border-left: none;
        border-right: 7px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        border-top: 7px solid transparent;
        left: -7px;
        top: 10px;
    }
    .navbar .sub-menu:after {
        border-top: 6px solid transparent;
        border-left: none;
        border-right: 6px solid #fff;
        border-bottom: 6px solid transparent;
        left: 10px;
        top: 11px;
        left: -6px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Afiliaciones</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Agregar <span class="caret"></span></a>
                   <ul class="dropdown-menu sub-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Trabajadores</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Empresarios</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Consultar </a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Actualizar </a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>      
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Con este código puedes hacer lo que necesitas

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <style>
      .dropdown-submenu {
          position: relative;
      }

      .dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu {
          top: 0;
          left: 100%;
          margin-top: -1px;
      }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
     
        <div class="container">
          
          <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Afiliaciones
                <span class="caret"></span></button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                    <a class="test" tabindex="-1" href="#">Agregar <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Opcion 1</a></li>
                      <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Opcion 2</a></li>
                      <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                        <a class="test" href="#">Otras opciones <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                          <li><a href="#">Opcion 1.1</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Opcion 1.1</a></li>
                      </ul>
                  </li>
              </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Consultar</a></li>
          <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Actualizar</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $('.dropdown-submenu a.test').on("click", function(e){
            $(this).next('ul').toggle();
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
        });
      });
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```